# Handwritten signature on mail in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to include handwritten signature of user on the email I am composing from code. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) for capturing handwritten signature on device. But the only problem I am facing is how to implement this code on mail. How can I handle *touch events* of mail.

What I decided for a moment was to capture a portion of mail screen on iPad on whose touching I can create a view where user can enter his/her signature which can further be saved. The only problem is implementing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can capture touches on mail composer. The best approach would be to ask user to sign and then present the mail composer with sign as attachment